# Count number of nodes per level in a binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I've been searching for a bit now and haven't been able to find anything similar to my question. Maybe i'm just not searching correctly. Anyways this is a question from my exam review. Given a binary tree, I need to output a list such that each item in the list is the number of nodes on a level in a binary tree at the items list index. What I mean, lst = [1,2,1] and the 0th index is the 0th level in the tree and the 1 is how many nodes are in that level. lst[1] will represent the number of nodes (2) in that binary tree at level 1. The tree isn't guaranteed to be balanced. We've only been taught preorder,inorder and postorder traversals, and I don't see how they would be useful in this question. I'm not asking for specific code, just an idea on how I could figure this out or the logic behind it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 1):

The search ordering doesn't really matter as long as you only count each node once. A depth-first search solution with recursion would be:

- Create a map `counters` to store a counter for each level. E.g. `counters[i]` is the number of nodes found so far at level `i`. Let's say level 0 is the root.
- Define a recursive function `count_subtree(node, level)`: Increment `counters[level]` once. Then for each child of the given node, call `count_subtree(child, level + 1)` (the child is at a 1-deeper level).
- Call `count_subtree(root_node, 0)` to count starting at the root. This will result in `count_subtree` being run exactly once on each node because each node only has one parent, so `counters[level]` will be incremented once per node. A leaf node is the base case (no children to call the recursive function on).
- Build your final list from the values of counters, ordered by their keys ascending.

This would work with any kind of tree, not just binary. Running time is O(number of nodes in tree). Side note: The depth-first search solution would be easier to divide and run on parallel processors or machines than a similar breadth-first search solution.